# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes in HTTPSConnection

Tags: python, http.client

I am trying to make an authorisation request and am coming up with the `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`. I have searched the web and have found similar issues but none of them help solve my issue. I am currently working in Jupyter (if that helps?) Also I am a python noob, so please be gentle...

Here is my code:

```py
import http.client as httplib
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
import requests as rq

base_url = 'api/url'
end_point = '/endpoint'
full_url = base_url + end_point

request_body = {
    'UserName':'un',
    'Password':'pw'
}

header = {
    'tenant': 'tenant name'  #required by vendor
}

print(type(base_url))
print(type(end_point))
print(type(full_url))
print(type(request_body))
print(type(header))

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(base_url)
    conn.request(method='POST',url=full_url, body=request_body, headers=header)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(type(data))
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Full traceback:

```py
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-1a19e8736fec> in <module>
     24     conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(base_url)
---> 25     conn.request(method='POST',url=full_url, body=request_body, headers=header)
     26     response = conn.getresponse()

~\Documents\Anaconda\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1243         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1244         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1245 

~\Documents\Anaconda\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1289             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1290         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1291 

~\Documents\Anaconda\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1238             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1239         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1240 

~\Documents\Anaconda\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1063                     chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\r\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \
-> 1064                         + b'\r\n'
   1065                 self.send(chunk)

TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-1a19e8736fec> in <module>
     30     conn.close()
     31 except Exception as e:
---> 32     print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'errno'
```

What am I missing here? What don't I understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this error is because of the `body=request_body` in the `request` method.

```
conn.request(method='POST',url=full_url, body=request_body, headers=header)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request)

> `body` may be a str, a bytes-like object, an open file object, or an
> iterable of bytes.

But in this case `request_body` is a dict object. So converting to JSON would probably fix this issue.

```
import json

conn.request(method='POST',url=full_url, body=json.dumps(request_body), headers=header)
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to fix it. I also found that using `urllib.parse.urlencode(request_body)` also works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error on get request any tips for that ?

Comment: @grepit Not sure if I will be able to answer the question without seeing the traceback? May be post it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

```py
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-75a4126e3e42> in <module>
     19 print(type(end_point))
     20 print(type(full_url))
---> 21 print(type(body_info))
     22 print(type(header))
     23 

NameError: name 'body_info' is not defined
```

You forgot to define 'body_info' or, most likely, you defined it as 'request_body' and didn't remember.

Fixing this line should be enough:

```py
body_info = {
    'UserName':'un',
    'Password':'pw'
}
```

instead of naming the dictionary `request_body`

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on my side. Still same issue when aligned.

Comment: sorry, i thought that's what you meant because i ran the code and got a coherent result:
```python
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```